# display text at the end of horizontal bar react chart js 2

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

[image]

Hi, I want to place the text at end of the bar. I can display within the bar, but someone suggest to display at the end. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code you already have. It will make it easier to propose a viable solution to solve your problem.